# merge multiple objects with sum of values from object array and rearrange the array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, flatten

I'm having array like this:

```
[{"an": "0",
  "ap": "11",
  "status":"active"
  "zr":"55"},
 {"an": "0",
  "ap": "15",
  "status":"death"
  "zr":"55"},
 {"an": "0",
  "ap": "18",
  "status":"recovered"
  "zr":"54"},
 {"an": "0",
  "ap": "11",
  "status":"active"
  "zr":"55"},
 {"an": "0",
  "ap": "11",
  "status":"death"
  "zr":"55"},
 {"an": "0",
  "ap": "11",
  "status":"recovered"
  "zr":"55"},
  {"an": "0",
  "ap": "11",
  "status":"active"
  "zr":"55"},
 {"an": "0",
  "ap": "11",
  "status":"death"
  "zr":"55"},
  {"an": "0",
  "ap": "11",
  "status":"recovered"
  "zr":"55"} ]
```

and I want to modify this array, so total modified array should be appeared like this

```
[ {"state":"an","active":"0", "death":"0", "recovered":"0"},{"state":"ap","active":"33", "death":"36", "recovered":"40"},{"state":"zr","active":"165", "death":"165", "recovered":"165"}]
```

I've tried method like groupby data according to status

```
var arr={};
    var result=data.map(({status, ...item}) =>{
        Object.keys(item).map((keys)=>{
            arr.state=keys;
            arr[status]= arr[status] ? arr[status] +item[keys] : item[keys];
        });
        return arr;
    })
    console.log(arr);
```

can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?
I want a common code in javascript which also can be applicable, if I have multiple keys to add.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please describe more the logic how you convert the first array to the second array

Comment: so I group the data according to status then iterate it by storing state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `status` and take the rest object for the values.

```js
var data = [{ an: "0", ap: "11", status: "active", zr: "55" }, { an: "0", ap: "15", status: "death", zr: "55" }, { an: "0", ap: "18", status: "recovered", zr: "54" }, { an: "0", ap: "11", status: "active", zr: "55" }, { an: "0", ap: "11", status: "death", zr: "55" }, { an: "0", ap: "11", status: "recovered", zr: "55" }, { an: "0", ap: "11", status: "active", zr: "55" }, { an: "0", ap: "11", status: "death", zr: "55" }, { an: "0", ap: "11", status: "recovered", zr: "55" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { status, ...o }) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([state, v]) => {
            r[state] = r[state] || { state };
            r[state][status] = ((+r[state][status] || 0) + +v).toString();
        });
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```